# removing forward slash, colons and AM/PM from a DateTime value

Tags: c#, datetime, replace

```
txtTest.text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

result in text box:

8/14/2012 10:06:48 AM

What would be the most efficient way of making it look like this?

8142012100648

I know about the replace/remove functions but I think there must be an easier way to do it.

by the way, the purpose of this is to generate unique file names.

Comment: `DateTime.Now.ToString("Mddyyyyhhmmss")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What would be the most efficient way of making it look like this?

Not calling `ToString` without a format specifier...

```
txtTest.text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MdyyyyHHmmss", 
                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I would strongly advise *against* this format though - would "1112012" be January 11th or November 1st?

I would suggest using an ISO-8601 style format would often be better: "yyyyMMddTHHmmss".

This will be unambiguous, and also sortable.

Comment: the point of this as i stated is to generate unique file names... i dont care about what day it is, you know what i mean? if i go by the second, the chances of 2 people generating a file at the same second is miniscule.

Comment: @user1336632: But why not just choose a sensible format to start with? Leaving ambiguity in there when there's *no* reason to seems a bad idea.

Comment: +1 from me. I wrote an answer too, but I deleted it since it wasn't greatly different from yours and, well, you need the rep Jon! ;-)

Comment: im going to but its telling me i gotta wait 7 min :(

Answer (score 0):

```
txtTest.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
```

Source: [Date - Time Stringformat overview in c#](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

this being just to remove the AM/PM, incase you want 24h-notations, check the provided url.